# <C-6> like mapping for browse through *all* open buffers in vim

Tags: vim

I am using `project` and `minibufexpl`(mbx) with my vim.
The problem is using `<C-6>`, the buffer only toggles between last two open buffer, and not the ***all*** buffers open.

I checked vim's  [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching) but it says about listing the buffer and then selecting them manually i.e. map for `:ls` and `:b`. Not much helpful.

Though, I can move through all the open buffers using mbx's way, (go to mbx window and keep pressing arrow), a  like alternative would have been helpful if it can span through *all* open buffers.

Any help please?

Comment: `:bn` and `:bN` may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to your problem seems to be to use Vim's built-in `:bn` and `:bN`.

See `:help buffers`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in vim 7.3 on a Linux installation.

To have Vim insert a character sequence instead of doing the action, prefix it with Ctrl+v or Ctrl+q (in Windows). So to get the map sequence for Ctrl+right arrow press Crtl+v, then Ctrl+right arrow to get Vim to insert ^[[1;5C, similarly ^[[1;5D for Ctrl+left arrow.

You can then add the following to your .vimrc file to cycle through all buffers by pressing Ctrl+right arrow or Ctrl+left arrow:

```
nmap ^[[1;5C :bn^M
nmap ^[[1;5D :bN^M
```

nmap does the mapping only for normal mode. The ^M means Ctrl+v, then <return>.